# Bundling with rollup a library that imports a legacy UMD library that uses conditional node require statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rollup

I am building an UMD library that is meant to be used only in browsers. However, it has a dependency on another UMD library/module/bundle .js file which contains require statements for nodejs modules. The statements aren't run always, but only if that sub-library detects it's running in NodeJS. For context, the required nodejs modules are `os`, `http` and `https` but they are all required dynamically.

My `rollup.config.js` is already using the `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` and `@rollup/plugin-typescript`. But when building it triggers some warnings.

```
(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins
Creating a browser bundle that depends on "os", "http" and "https". You might need to include https://github.com/FredKSchott/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
(!) Missing global variable names
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputglobals
Use "output.globals" to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules:
os (guessing "require$$0")
http (guessing "require$$1")
https (guessing "require$$2")
```

The resulting generated bundle file:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('os'), require('http'), require('https')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'os', 'http', 'https'], factory) :
    (global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, factory((global.ns_ = global.ns_ || {}, global.ns_.Bundle = {}), global.require$$0, global.require$$1, global.require$$2));
})(this, (function (exports, require$$0, require$$1, require$$2) { 'use strict';

// ...

// Pseudo-code
if(node) {
  const os = require$$0;
  //...
}
```

The bundler has replaced my `require('os')` statements with `require$$0` so it isn't calling the require statements "conditionally" as I would have expected. They have been pre-called (hoisted). Any way for Rollup to not do hoisting of that?

Answer (score 2):

It is stated pretty clearly in the warnings that the `os`, `http`, and `https` modules are being included in browser bundle and that Rollup is unable to determine the correct global variable names for these modules.

You can use the suggested `output.globals` option in your Rollup configuration to specify the correct global variable names for these modules.

Something like:

```
export default {
  output: {
    globals: {
      os: 'os',
      http: 'http',
      https: 'https',
    },
  },
  // other options
};
```

### -OR-

You could also use `@rollup/plugin-polyfill-node` (by including it as is in your Rollup configuration) to automatically include polyfills for these built-in Node.js modules.

Let me know if this does it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this does not fix the problem. The errors are still appearing and the hosting, the real problem, is still there. It also adds a huge amount of code.